# SOT-23 device identification

Tags: transistors, diodes, components, identification

I have a small SOT-23 (3 pins, transistor-like) device that burned out (shorted between 2 pins). I need to identify it so i can replace it, but i can't find the code at all. 
The code is: SE and a simbol like a horizontal "P". Like this image:

[image]

Here's a picture of the device, although i don't think it will help much:

[image]

I'm not sure if it's a transistor, FET or diode.. It belongs (apparently) to a driver circuit for a P-Channel Power Mosfet, but that's all i can share because the circuit is almost impossible to follow.

Looked the code up on many webpages and can't find anything but a "2SC4703" RF transistor, but it's definetly not one suited for the actual circuit.

Any help would be apreciated.

Comment: A photo could help.

Comment: Picture of the SOT-23 device would greatly help solve your issue.

Comment: Well.. *this* photo is not very helpful :) We can't see what is written there..

Comment: @EugeneSh. Really... i'm telling you exactly what it says.. checked by 3 different people and with a microscope... If the only analisis here is wheter i'm blind or a liar it is not very helpfull

Comment: You can *misinterpret* it. Anyway. We can try from the other direction. Which driver is that? Something of-the-shelf or custom? Does it have similar parts?

Comment: it's connected to the gate of a p channel mosfet

Comment: I can take a wild guess.... a protection diode for the gate.  Schottky diodes are also used to control turn-on/turn-off speed.

Comment: It could also be an n-channel to pull down the p-channel.... Basically without a circuit diagram it could be any number of a lot of things that come in that package. At least a partial schematic of the area would help... get your beeper out.

Answer (score 2):

It is most likely a Schottky barrier diode to accelerate the turn-on/turn-off speed of the gate of the PMOS.  From the information given, it is hard to point on what consumer it is actually from.  We would need more details for this.  But what you could do is unsoldered the part and perform a few test to confirm my hypothesis.

Apply a small voltage (0.5V) and put a small load on either pin on the side with two pins.  See if it conducts.  Apply a larger voltage (2-5V) and look at the voltage drop of the diode (if it is indeed a diode).

You could also put the part on a curve tracer to see the characteristics like the breakdown voltage and the forward voltage.  It is either two Schottky barrier diodes in parallel or a single one as shown below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

For a PMOS device, I would expect the diode to be arrange like the middle picture.  Either single or double.

Comment: If not for the following list i found, i would have marked this as the answer, but i must ask: I found this list from 2007 (of course, not a very reliable source: google): http://caxapa.ru/thumbs/588912/smd-codes.pdf, that leads to this device: http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-SMBT2907A-DS-v01_01-en.pdf?fileId=db3a30431441fb5d011445fe084a0190 . Is there a tipical p-mosfet drive circuit that would use a pnp transistor like the one on the list (the code in the list related to the SE marking on my original device)

Comment: the list apparently comes from http://www.turuta.md

Comment: @ndelucca Have you found what part it is?

Comment: I wasn't sure this could be a diode, so i took another step. I looked everywhere on the board until i found another part with the same code...which i did!, so i took it out and tested it, it turned up to be a PNP diode, furthermore, it appears that this mosfet is being used to drop from 24Vdc to 8 - 9 Vdc, to power some buck converters.. I still don't know the specifications for the transistor, i seems to me that it's not a simplre 30mA transistor, i still dont know how to find this out..

Comment: Alright, nice findings!  Testing a PNP Mosfet can be done easily.  Essentially, you could put your Mosfet through a sequence of tests to find out some of the main specifications such as Vt, Vds max, Id max, and so on.  I would say begin by identifying the pinout of the package and then find the threshold for the gate voltage.  After that, try establishing some type of Vd/Id characteristics curve with different Vg.

Comment: My apologies! I said PNP "diode"!, i meant PNP transistor. The test i did was very basic, the pinout was simple to find out according to how it was connected. I used 5v and a few resistors and used it as a switch. I believe its a BJT not a MOSFET, but how can i be sure of this?

Comment: I am not exactly sure, but I will give you a hint:  A BJT is current-controlled whereas a MOSFET is voltage-controlled.  MOSFET gates have extremely high impedance.